# Ошибка при установке модуля simple-crypt

Tags: python, windows

При установке модуля выдает такую ошибку. Кто-нибудь сталкивался?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам в ошибке прямым текстом написано, что не так.

Comment: увы, нынче программисту надо знать английский...

Comment: `pip install simple-crypt`

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, напомните когда это было не так? ))))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets чтобы читать трассы достаточно хотя бы уметь пользоваться Google Translate.

Answer (score 2):

Неверное название модуля в команде установки. 
Согласно  [документации](https://pypi.org/project/simple-crypt/) должно быть так:

```
pip install simple-crypt
```